# Run Instant App with mac mini m1 2020 and (Android studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 patch 2) now whit Giraffe 2022.3.1

Tags: android, macos, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to run an instant app from mac mini m1 2020 and Android studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 patch 2 and Giraffe 2022.3.1, but nothing works.

I have a configuration with module of **instant.main** and checked **Deploy as instant app**.

But on my pc with windows and the same configuration and the same version of Android studio, everything works

Configuration:
[Config Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L59hA.png)

I tried with the emulator and physical device, but in every situation I have this in the run tab:
[Run Tab Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cnv6.png)

Now with new Android studio versione, when a I run the instant module, he gives to me this error message:

`could not initialize class com.google.android.instantapps.sdk.lib.ClearcutLogger`

Comment: Got the same problem here but on Windows.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have the same problem, running on Mac Apple Silicon + Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed with Hedgehog Canary 12. You can use the relevant version.

[Hedgehog Canary 12](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2023/07/android-studio-hedgehog-canary-12-now.html)

Comment: Can confirm it does. Thank you

Comment: This saved me a lot of time and headaches. Thank you.