# Error running app in Android Studio due to "cannot access class because module does not export to unnamed module"

Tags: android, class, export

I'm new to Android Studio, and I wanted to incorporate Instant App capabilities to a sample app I've created so I can be familiar with how to apply it to a real app. However, when I'm running the app on my phone, I get an error saying "

```
class com.google.android.instantapps.sdk.lib.ClearcutLogger cannot access class sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net.www.protocol.https to unnamed module"
```

. The build goes through fine, but when I run the app, I get this error. The sample app only has a button and a text box, and it's worked before I tried to incorporate the sample app, so it has something to do with incorporating the sample app.

I've tried different things, such as trying to add dependencies or use 'add-exports' from what I've seen on other Stack Overflow questions, but I can't find anything that works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a problem with the latest Android Studio version.
When tried the same project with Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1 version it works ok.
Every version of Android Studio after that is not working.

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem as well, running Flamingo on MacOS Apple Silicon. There's also a bounty on a question about the same problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76853530/run-instant-app-with-mac-mini-m1-2020-and-android-studio-flamingo-2022-2-1-patc